# not able to see the preview Window for swiftui and simulator showing my mac

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I have enabled the canvas but still not able to see anything. I checked on hacking with swift but couldn't find anything. Also instead of simulators it only shows my mac.

[I can only see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFeq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are making a macOs application instead of an iOS app. When you create a project, make sure you have selected iOS rather than macOs.

[image]